# Is it possible to have both an internal and external build active in TestFlight?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight, beta

Our company is currently running a beta test using TestFlight, and we're looking to push a new build that has several major changes.  We'd like to test to make sure nothing's catastrophically wrong with the new build before pushing it, but unfortunately many people here work remotely and we can't manually install the new build on their devices.

What I'd like to do is upload a new build to iTunes Connect, and not submit it for review until we've had a chance to test it.  According to Apple:

> As you upload new builds for a prerelease version, internal testers will always get the most recent build you uploaded. External testers get access to the update only after you have submitted it to Beta App Review and it has been approved.

This is good.  This is exactly what I want.  However, on the next line, they go on to say:

> Uploading a new build will automatically disable new installations of older builds.

What I'm understanding that to mean is that if you upload a new internal build, nobody will be able to install the old external build.  Is that right?  And if so, is there any way to have a second, internal test version?

Comment: I know this question is old, but I feel that it is important to point out that you assumption that you "can't manually install the new build on their devices" is incorrect.  Without using TestFlight or iTunesConnect, you can create an ad-hoc build and send it to someone directly so they can install it on their device, or distribute it for free to them via email by using Fabric.  You will also need to add their device UDID manually to your apple developer portal list of approved devices. Then, anyone with an approved device can install your app to test it before pushing updates to TestFlight.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see your misunderstanding here. How it works is that when you upload a new build, all your Internal Testers will be notified and be able to download the new version. Only fro internal testers the previous version will be disabled, while external testers will be able to download the last reviewed version of your app for up to 30 days. Only when you'll also submit your new build for external testing review you will update your external tester's version. Until then they'll be able to download the current version. Hope that helps,
Julian

Comment: That's super helpful, thanks so much!  One quick follow up, does it matter if you upload the new one as a new build or an entirely new version?

Comment: Hey Adam. Absolutely not. Change the version or build number. It'll work anyways :-)